# How to extract/compute leverage and Cook's distances for linear mixed effects models

Tags: r, mixed-model, linear-model, residuals, leverage

Does anyone know how to compute (or extract) leverage and Cook's distances for a `mer` class object (obtained through `lme4` package)?
I'd like to plot these for a residuals analysis.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should have a look at the R package `influence.ME`. It allows you to compute measures of influential data for mixed effects models generated by `lme4`.

An example model:

```
library(lme4)
model <- lmer(mpg ~ disp + (1 | cyl), mtcars)
```

The function `influence` is the basis for all further steps:

```
library(influence.ME)
infl <- influence(model, obs = TRUE)
```

Calculate Cook's distance:

```
cooks.distance(infl)
```

Plot Cook's distance:

```
plot(infl, which = "cook")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This certainly helps. How about computing the leverage for a Cook's distance vs. leverage plot?

Comment: @RoeyAngel I suppose this is not possible with the `influence.ME` package. Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for this task.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `infl <- influence(model, group = "cyl")`, because you specified random effect as `(1|cyl)`? I don't know, I don't understand this at all, I just installed influence... but I don't really know when to use `obs = TRUE` and when to use `group`...

Comment: I would like to add the following: If you would like to get the row number that Cook's D distances occur - the same number occuring in the plot without plotting, then you may use the following r formula about Cooks' D distances numbers with a cut off value of e.g. 0.1 `cooksD_data<-as.data.frame(cooks.distance(ft1))
cooksD_data_select<-cooksd[cooksD_data>0.1,drop=FALSE,]
cooksD_oultiers<-as.numeric(rownames(cooksD_data_select))]`

Comment: Is this any better than the `hatvalues()` function [recommended here](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/MM/MM_DiagInfer.html)?