# How to extract/compute leverage and Cook's distances for Generalised Additive models

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, leverage

Similar to the following question,

[How to extract/compute leverage and Cook's distances for linear mixed effects models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54818/how-to-extract-compute-leverage-and-cooks-distances-for-linear-mixed-effects-mo)

Is there any method in R to determine influential points in a GAM?

Answer (score 1):

If your model is quick to fit, you can calculate a leave-one-out measure of sample influence manually like this:

```
mref <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = DAT)
fref <- fitted(mref)

f <- function(index) {
  dat <- DAT[-index, ]
  m <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = dat)

  # sum of squared differences between this fit and reference model
  # based on full dataset
  sum( (fref[-index] - fitted(m))^2 )
}

influence <- sapply(1:nrow(DAT), f)
```

Comment: Thanks but how do you determine how big the sum of squared differences has to be to for a point to be influential?.

Comment: @user53020 Rather than taking any particular threshold, I would take the values as a relative measure of influence and look for any that stand out from the rest, as per [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22171/133387)